# Why videoPlayerController.value.isPlaying = false after videoPlayerController.play() is called?

Tags: flutter

Recently I am using flutter plugin vieo_player, during the time I encounter a problem:

videoPlayerController.value.isPlaying's value is false after videoPlayerController.play() is called, which I expected to be true.

```
VideoPlayerController get controller => widget.controller;
controller.play();
print("isPlaying = ${controller.value.isPlaying}");// print false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is play() is an async function:

[image]

When value.position == value.duration, it will run into await line, in which case controller.value will not change immediately.

If you use await before controller.play(), controller.value.isPlaying will be true.

Comment: For you, this means that you need to call `await controller.play();`.